# Accessing data from date of birth to get the age

Tags: php, laravel-5, php-carbon

```
Sample Database
Id          scholar_birthday
1           2001-12-05
2           2002-10-15
3           1991-12-19
4           1990-02-25
```

I am having a problem with my code in getting the data from the database column *scholar_birthday*. What I want here is to get the year, month, and day individually so that i can pass them as parameters to *createFromFormat()*.

```
$input  = Scholar::select('scholar_birthday')->get(); 
$strFromArr = serialize($input);
$format = 'Y/m/d';
$year = 'Y';
$month = 'm';
$day = 'd';
dd($format);
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat($year,$month,$day, $strFromArr);
dd($date);
```

But the result (the return value from *dd()*) is:

> A four digit year could not be found

Does anyone have an idea on how to implement this the correct way?

Comment: maybe you could auto parse the values to a Carbon object, by adding scholar_birthday to the private $dates attribute in the Model (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators)

Comment: @mikro911 - Sir actually i'm using laravel 5.0 in my project.

Answer (score 0):

This is best handled in the mysql query.

```
SELECT YEAR(scholar_birthday) as year, 
       MONTH(scholar_birthday) as month, 
       DAY(scholar_birthday) as day
FROM Scholar
```

Now I am not completely familiar with the laravel model, but it looks like you can do this...

```
$fields = "YEAR(scholar_birthday) as year, MONTH(scholar_birthday) as month, DAY(scholar_birthday) as day";
$input  = Scholar::select($fields)->get();
```